# Publish wizard doesn't have Single File Executable Option

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i am using visual studio 2017 with .net 4.8 and when i hit publish the option for Self-Contained app or Single File option doesn't show and i tried opening the project with Visual Studio 2020 and still the option doesn't show.
this is a WPF application

[Publish Wizard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T2pA.png)

[Publish Wizard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjhrw.png)

[Publish Wizard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEzv5.png)

[Publish Wizard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJ7xu.png)

Comment: [This deployment model has been available since .NET Core 3.0 and has been enhanced in .NET 5.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview)

Comment: so why can't i find that option ?

Comment: Because .NET Framework is not . NET Core

Comment: so i can't publish this in a single file ?

Comment: Not with .Net Framework

Comment: No, .NET Framework doesn't offer this option out of the box. However, there might be some third-party tools that get that done as well. However, if you have a self-extracting installer, it's not really required IMHO.

Comment: There's no option to publish that I know of but there are ways to merge assemblies you might look into (ilmerge) but I don't really have experience with that

Comment: Do you appreciate that .net fw 4.8 is not the precursor to .net 5/not preceded by netcore 3? The numbering is a bit unfortunately misleading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file/overview).

This deployment model has been available since .NET Core 3.0 and has been enhanced in .NET 5. Previously in .NET Core 3.0, when a user ran your single-file application, the .NET Core host first extracted all the files into a directory before running the application.

.NET 5 improves this experience by running the code directly without extracting files from the application.

So the answer to that question is, you can't use single file publishing under .net 4.8.